# How practical is mid-air cargo transfer?

Tags: cargo

Mid-air refueling is now commonplace and I have even heard that [passenger transfer in mid-air has been possible for stunts](https://www.quora.com/Could-you-transfer-from-one-aircraft-to-another-mid-flight). What is the practicality of mid-air cargo transfer?

Comment: Are you asking if mid-air cargo transfer of cargo for a stunt is practical?  Or are you envisioning some commercial application? What general type of aircraft are you thinking of would be involved?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-air_retrieval

Comment: The same practicality of transferring 'packages' from makeshift submarines onto boats with four 250hp outboards on them.

Comment: You could quote an excerpt from Quora that you find particularly relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly using a long tube to transfer cargo would be insane, and as others have said it's generally impractical. But, let's assume that for some reason it really needs to be done, and the importance of this outweighs the complications and inefficiencies.

Transferring fuel from one plane to another is already possible. Flight control surfaces are installed on the nozzle to allow an operator to accurately control its position relative to the receiving plane. Why don't we learn from that?

[image: Mid air refueling]

**Scenario 1:**

Transfer of cargo by zip line: The receiving plane is equipped with loading doors on the top. A zip line emerges from the back of the first plane, and is steered using control surfaces down into the cargo bay of the receiving plane. When it arrives, an operator attaches it to a fixture so that it's secure.

Next, cargo boxes are sent to slide down the zip line, using some device to slow their motion. The operators in the receiving plane receive them detach them from the line, and pack them onto the cargo hold.

**Scenario 2:**

Transfer of cargo by aerodynamic body: What if the cargo could be 'flown' from one plane to the next? The cargo is packed into an aerodynamic container which emerges from the back of the first plane, attached by three tethers.

[image: Aerodynamic lifting body]

The cargo can be steered by controlling the lengths of these three tethers. This gives 3 degrees of freedom in the control, allowing the cargo to be steered relative to the second plane, which is following the first plane at a slightly lower altitude. Again there are cargo doors on the top of the plane to accept the cargo. Alternatively, the cargo simply attaches to the top of the receiving plane, like the space shuttle.

[image: Shuttle on 747]

Comment: The cargo is Hatsune Miku?

Answer (score 26):

It's technically feasible to do this, there are mid-air capture systems already, developed to snag payloads returning from space (film, samples, etc) which are descending by parachute. There are fixed wing and helicopter versions of the technology. So, you could drop a cargo out of the back of one airplane, and another could catch it, winch it in and fly it somewhere else. In fact, technically this has been done numerous time as the testing of these systems and training of the pilots involved pushing the test article out of the back of another airplane.

The reasons it's impractical to use this are:

1. It's expensive: The hardware costs money and adds weight to the aircraft, the aircraft have to be unpressurized if the cargo is to be winched in, which some cargo won't tolerate, the aircraft will have much less capacity due to the equipment involved, and other reasons
2. It's dangerous: Flying an aircraft into a parachute or other drop system is inherently hazardous, it's only done when there's no other alternative
3. It's weather intolerant: whatever solution is used, the transfer would need decent weather conditions, and probably need to be done during the day, which would limit it's utility
4. It has no practical benefit: transferring cargo from one perfectly good airplane to another one doesn't get the cargo there faster, safer, or cheaper. If the cargo needs to go where an airplane can't land then it can be transferred to another one, or to a helicopter at a field. If time is of the essence then the cargo can be air-dropped. There's no problem that mid-air cargo transfer solves

Comment: Footnote: Air drops can already use steerable parachute systems.  Air-launched UAVs would provide the manoeuvrability of a small aircraft after transferring from a  large, fast, long-range aircraft, but without the transfer, if there was a need for greater range or precision away from the parent aircraft

Comment: "the aircraft have to be unpressurized if the cargo is to be winched in, which some cargo won't tolerate"
If the cargo can't handle the unpressurized aircraft, then it probably would already be damaged before it gets winched in. Considering where it came from :)

Comment: @ChrisH the air-launched UAVs already exist too, e.g. the Silent Arrow GD-2000

Comment: @ErinAnne I thought read something about it, but couldn't track it down again having forgotten the name

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: air dropped... the original "drop shipping" (hehe)

Comment: "There's no problem that mid-air cargo transfer solves" except of course saving President Harrison Ford.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Unwbu-dhYM

Comment: "doesn't get the cargo there faster, safer, or cheaper" - but it does *get there*. And if coca doesn't grow well in your climate....

Comment: This honestly sounds like something that would only be practical in the craziest of emergencies, like the President Harrison reference @Ryan_L made or if you were reacting to a crazy dynamic battlefield scenario where you had two planes in range and only one of them had any bombs left and you needed to hit two targets simultaneously, and immediately. Would make for good fiction, at any rate.

Comment: "transferring cargo from one perfectly good airplane to another one doesn't get the cargo there faster, safer, or cheaper" - Unless the first aircraft is low on fuel, and the second one full.  Midair refueling would be better, but maybe the first aircraft is incapable of that for whatever reason.

Comment: If the first plane is low on fuel it needs to land @aroth, not loiter while cargo is transferred.

Comment: "Low" in this context ought to be interpreted as "not enough fuel to fly the cargo directly to its final destination, but enough to effect a successful mid-air transfer to a second plane that _can_ reach the final destination".  I'll grant that it's risky and expensive, but as long as the transfer isn't unreasonably slow it should get the cargo there faster than landing, refueling, and taking off again.

Answer (score 6):

Grossly impractical, and manifestly unsafe as well. Here are a few reasons why.

To transfer cargo from one plane to another requires mechanized material handling systems which can be extended hundreds of feet through the air from one plane to the other and retracted again when the job is done, while the plane is flying at perhaps 200MPH or more. Every pound of material handling machinery built into a plane represents a pound of lost payload, in a business where a fuel cost increase of order ~pennies per pound is enough to ground an entire fleet of cargo planes.

Now imagine the size of the cargo conduit itself. It will have to pass objects the size of a preloaded cargo bin, perhaps 6 feet on a side, so the conduit will be about 8 feet across and let's say 100 feet long.

That tube will be extending through the slipstream of one plane and into the oncoming flow field of the other plane at very high Reynolds numbers; the flow fields surrounding both planes will be significantly upset by the presence of that tube and that disturbance will grow from nothing to its full extent as the tube gets extended on a timescale of ~100 seconds.

Both planes need to be fully controllable before, during, and after the transfer process which will involve the exchange of one plane's full useful cargo load to the other, leaving one empty plane at max gross and one plane at max gross empty.

And during that process, the two planes will be physically connected together and flying at the same speed, which will require both of them to be actively trimming and modulating their power settings the whole time.

And the whole shebang must be resistant to perturbations from the environment.

...and for what purpose, exactly?

Comment: In my head there's a fleet of drones taking off from all over the UK carrying small amounts of cargo up to a 'mother-ship' that crosses an ocean (perhaps the Atlantic), then drops the drones on the other side, to deposit their cargo.

Comment: @Richard Why not just load the mothership on the ground, with cargo arriving at the sorting facility via trucks & smaller aircraft, like the way FedEx moves packages around? Take as long as you need to (within reason) to load the cargo, not burning fuel waiting for the last package to arrive.

Comment: @RalphJ - Think of the mothership as a conveyor belt. You'd have multiples of these things in continuous motion. The drone wouldn't need to travel to a central location. It would just join the mothership as it moves overhead

Comment: Cocaine is a helluva drug.

Comment: Richard's idea might get practical with a nuclear powered large aircraft, but this comments thread is becoming like WordlbuildingSE.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not what you mean, but this could be practical when one craft is so large (and slow) it can wholly contain another, such as a cargo or "aircraft carrier" rigid airship.

However, these crafts themselves are considered to be impractical ([CargoLifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CargoLifter), [DARPA Walrus/HULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walrus_HULA)), I believe largely due to the impracticality of acquiring and [maintaining storage of helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_storage_and_conservation) (which is [hugely safer than hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ_129_Hindenburg#Use_of_hydrogen_instead_of_helium), but still sneaks out of everything because it's so small)

Answer (score 1):

While mid-air cargo transfer is technically feasible, its practicality is limited in most cargo transportation scenarios. The complexities of coordinating multiple aircraft, ensuring safe cargo attachment and detachment, and maintaining stability during the transfer make it challenging. Additionally, the cost-effectiveness and efficiency of mid-air cargo transfer compared to ground-based methods raise concerns. Although it may have niche applications, mid-air cargo transfer is not widely employed in real-world cargo logistics operations.